# Creating an image from an unmanaged buffer

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, unsafe

I need to display an image in a WPF application written in C#. The image content is generated by an external unmanaged library, which allocates the raster buffer itself.

I am trying to wrap that buffer in a `BitmapSource` object (attached as the `Source` of an `Image` control) using the `Create` method, but the method takes a byte array whereas all I have is an `IntPtr` to the buffer.

Is there a way to create a byte array from an unmanaged buffer ? Preferably without copying ? (I know  that what I am doing is unsafe, but the buffer is guaranteed to persist for the whole lifetime of the application).

Or is there an alternative way to display a raster image from an unmanaged buffer into an `Image` or `Canvas` object or similar ?

---

**Update:**

I just missed that there is an overload of `BitmapSource.Create` that takes an `IntPtr` ! (Though I don't know if that copies the image or not.)

Comment: I have seen many posts with similar requirements, but so far none truly answered my need.

Comment: The problem with that is that an wpf image needs a save format instead of raw bytes. You could try to write a header (for example uncompressed tiff) and concat the data on it. _(too bad, it requires a copy)_ It **is** possible to bind an byte array to an image.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How about using the [BitmapSource.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.create?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-media-imaging-bitmapsource-create(system-int32-system-int32-system-double-system-double-system-windows-media-pixelformat-system-windows-media-imaging-bitmappalette-system-intptr-system-int32-system-int32)) overload that takes an IntPtr argument?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: there is no need for a header if you pass a byte array. (And in any case, I don't see a way to pass raw bytes.)

Comment: @Clemens: Create does not take an InPtr, it takes an Array. This is where the problem stands.

Comment: There are [two overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.create?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), one with Array, the other with IntPtr.

Comment: @Clemens: ooops, that's right. Trying this ASAP.

Comment: How large image are we talking about? Do you want to avoid copies due to some memory or performance concerns?

Comment: @JonasH: yes perfomance. Like 2 Mpixels RGB, displayed live. (And also just for the sake of avoiding unnecessary copies.)

Comment: @Clemens: ooops, my very bad, I referred to the wrong image. Working now ! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The size of the image must be defined somewhere. The size of the image does not have to match the size of the control.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: er, why do you tell me ? This has nothing to do with a header. My question has nothing to do with the image file formats, just bitmaps in memory.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Uhm, either you put in a image file format (bind byte array to image) or use something like Clemens suggested, create a bitmap source (where you specify the dimensions of the image)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: thanks for your contribution. The problem was completely solved yesterday and the solution works fine since.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, I saw a great answer. _(I wasn't quite in the right direction, I guess.)_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Also "*bind byte array to image*" sounds odd. In order to create a BitmapSource from an encoded frame buffer like a PNG or JPEG, you would set the StreamSource property of a BitmapImage or use BitmapFrame.Create with a stream argument, where the Stream contains the buffer. If you bind the Source property of an Image element to a byte array, a BitmapFrame is created by implicit type conversion, i.e. an instance of the ImageSourceConverter class.

Comment: We're using a bytearray that is bound to an Image.Source, the bytearray contains a jpeg image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a BitmapSource from an unmanaged raw pixel buffer, use the [BitmapSource.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.create?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-media-imaging-bitmapsource-create(system-int32-system-int32-system-double-system-double-system-windows-media-pixelformat-system-windows-media-imaging-bitmappalette-system-intptr-system-int32-system-int32)) method, e.g. like this:

```
PixelFormat format = PixelFormats.Bgr24;
int width = 768;
int height = 576;
int stride = (width * format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
int size = stride * height;

IntPtr buffer = ...

BitmapSource bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(
    width, height, 96, 96, format, null, buffer, size, stride);
```

---

In case you want to cyclically update the Source of an Image element, it may may be more efficient to overwrite the buffer of a single WriteableBitmap instead of reassigning the Image's Source with a new BitmapSource in each cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [WriteableBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). While this do require a copy, it should not need any allocations, and I would expect the performance to be well within the requirements for a live view.

```
myWriteableBitmap.WritePixels(
    new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height),
    bufferPointer,
    bufferSize,
    stride);
```